# Playing RTMP stream with VideoJS player

Tags: html, video-streaming, video.js, rtmp

I'm trying to play `RTMP` stream with `VideoJS` player, below is my code:

```
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 --> 
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{"techorder" : ["flash"]}'>
    <source src="rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" type="rtmp/mp4">                                                                                                                           
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

The error I'm seeing is this:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media. MediaError {code: 4, message: "No compatible source was found for this media."}

The error is quite clear, but there are plenty of docs showing people success stories of playing `RTMP` streams with `VideoJS`:

- [Stream video with rtmp and videojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940721/stream-video-with-rtmp-and-videojs)
- [How to play rtmp live stream using videojs？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271187/how-to-play-rtmp-live-stream-using-videojs)

I know for sure that the following URL does play on `VLC` player and so does it on `JWPlayer`:

```
rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna play `RTMP` you must include `flash-tech` which can be retrieved from here:

```
https://github.com/videojs/videojs-flash
```

Hence correct code would be this:

```
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 --> 
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{"techorder" : ["flash"]}'>
    <source src="rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" type="rtmp/mp4">                                                                                                                           
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video.js"></script>
  <script src="/videojs-flash.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried this example but its not working can you help me. i am not seeing any error in webconsole but video was not playing, i included videojs flash js file.

Comment: Can you confirm that your RTMP stream is actually working, for instance can you play it with VLC player? If you comment out videojs-flash.js line, do you get any errors in the console? What are you using to stream RTMP? I was using Nginx plugin.

Comment: I am able play video using VLC player. if i commented out videojs flash tag videojs returning MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED  can you please check  my code https://jsfiddle.net/qco58Lef/   Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to confirm, that it doesn't work anymore.. A bug or incompatibility between projects, I don't know (as `videojs-flash` seem to be subdivision of `videojs`). BTW, in your jsfiddle you did not include videojs-flash.js.