# Is there any videojs + rtmp example that can run?

Tags: javascript, video, streaming, video.js, rtmp

It has taken me several hours to play rtmp video using videojs. Can anyone give an example that can just run?

I am using chrome. Flash is enabled.

Below is my code. Video url is valid. Can anyone make it run?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/video.js@7.3.0/dist/video-js.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/video.js@7.3.0/dist/video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-flash@2.1.2/dist/videojs-flash.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<video width="600"
       height="400"
       id="example"
       class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
       controls
       autoplay
       preload="auto"
       data-setup='{"techorder" : ["flash","html5"] }'>
    <source src="rtmp://rtmp.open.ys7.com/openlive/f01018a141094b7fa138b9d0b856507b.hd" type="rtmp/mp4">
</video>

</body>
<script>
    var player = videojs('example');
    player.play();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, you found the previous discussion thread from a year ago:
    [Playing RTMP stream with VideoJS player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146146/playing-rtmp-stream-with-videojs-player)
which indicates that others have had difficulty and did NOT succeed.

Now that HTML5 is firmly established, Flash video is rapidly disappearing, as
mentioned four years ago:
    https://www.theverge.com/2015/1/27/7926001/youtube-drops-flash-for-html5-video-default

It is very straightforward to convert flash-video into more modern formats...one
such article for using an excellent free open-source tool for conversion is here:
    https://addpipe.com/blog/flv-to-mp4/

So, rather than try to solve your technical problem, I would recommend, if at all
possible, to bring your videos up to present-day technology.

Comment: rtmp is still a very common live streaming source and you don't always have control of the source yourself.